# How to create a Pixi.js Smoke Mask?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pixi.js

I wanted to create a Pixi.js Smoke Mask for my junior level portfolio. I'm not sure where to begin. I know the basics of Pixi.js but not sure how to make something cool like a smoke mask.

This is a general idea of what I'm , trying to create:

https://designmodo.com/smoke-transitions/

Can you help?﻿ Or is there another approach?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your answer in the same link you shared. The link your shared has 2 areas at the bottom with the follow headings:

1. Smoke Effects in CSS and JavaScript
2. Pixi.js

If you click on the images of these sections. You will see that 1 takes you to codepad.co example code and 2 takes you to codepen.io example code.

You can learn from there how you can achieve your goal. No one here can help you by giving you a completely built solution. Try learning from those samples and then work on your solution. Then if you are having any issues in your solution. Share your problem code here for us to help out.

Hope this guides you. Happy Coding.

Comment: Okay thank you. I did want to understand the code to do it, thank you for guiding me.

Comment: @harp Just to add to NasirT:s answer: I really doubt you will get completely built solution, but if you are having trouble with it, you can always also ask from here: http://www.html5gamedevs.com/ . More pixi-experts there, that might be able to help you in the right direction.